# Executor in java

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

I was trying to run `ExecutorService` object with `FixedThreadPool` and I ran into problems.

I expected the program to run in nanoseconds but it was hung. I found that I need to use `Semaphore` along with it so that the items in the queue do not get added up.

Is there any way I can come to know that all the threads of the pool are used.

Basic code ...

```
static ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
static Semaphore permits = new Semaphore(4);
try {
    permits.acquire();
    pool.execute(p);  // Assuming p is runnable on large number of objects
    permits.release();
} catch ( InterruptedException ex ) {
}
```

This code gets hanged and I really don't know why. How to know if pool is currently waiting for all the threads to finish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, if you submit more than 4 tasks to your pool then the extra tasks will be queued until a thread becomes available.

The blog you referenced in your comment uses the semaphore to limit the amount of work that can be queued at once, which won't be a problem for you until you have many thousands of tasks queued up and they start eating into the available memory. <s>There's an easier way to do this, anyway - construct a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) with a bounded queue.</s>* **But this isn't your problem.**

If you want to know when a task completes, notice that `ExecutorService.submit()` returns a `Future` object which can be used to wait for the task's completion:

```
Future<?> f = pool.execute(p);
f.get();
System.out.println("task complete");
```

If you have several tasks and want to wait for all of them to complete, either store each  `Future` in a list and then call `get()` on each in turn, or investigate `ExecutorService.invokeAll()` (which essentially does the same but in a single method call).

You can also tell whether a task has completed or not:

```
Future<?> f = pool.execute(p);

while(!f.isDone()) {
    // do something else, task not complete
}

f.get();
```

Finally, note that even if your tasks are complete, your program may not exit (and thus appears to "hang") if you haven't called `shutdown()` on the thread pool; the reason is that the threads are still running, waiting to be given more work to do.

***Edit:** sorry, I just re-read my answer and realised this part is incorrect - [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) *offers* tasks to the queue and rejects them if they aren't accepted, so a bounded queue has different semantics to the semaphore approach.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the Semaphore.

If you are hanging it is probably because the threads are locking themselves elsewhere.

Run the code in a Debuger and when it hangs pause it and see what the threads are doing.

Comment: I think the semaphore is there because there's no other way to block if all 4 threads are occupied - the executor would throw an exception, whereas we need it to block the submitting thread.

Comment: Which exceptions are you seeing being thrown ? The new tasks you submit should just be queued up by the Executor if all threads are busy.

Comment: Hey I read this blog and assumed that I need to make ssemaphores. http://blog.readpath.com/2010/01/20/java-fixedthreadpool/

Comment: @user506710 You do not need it.

Answer (score 0):

You could change to using a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). It contains a `getActiveCount()` method which returns an **approximate** count of the active threads. Why it is approximate I'm not sure.

Comment: The count could become invalid if a thread finishes execution during `getActiveCount()`'s calculation, or just before it returns the answer to the caller.

Comment: Is there no way I come to know that executor service is currently being blocked ? I mean there has to be a way to let the other threads going to sleep mode till the used ones are running.......

Comment: @user596710 I've never used ExecutorService before. My suggestion is purely based a on a little exploration of the javdocs. However, a little more exploration revealed the following.They state that any additional tasks given to your Fixed ThreadPool should be added to the queue and await a free thread. That your application is hanging suggests the issue lies with the tasks you are running rather than the ExecutorService

Comment: @user506710: not sure what you mean in your comment - all of the threads in the pool will be running until they run out of work to do, i.e. there are no more tasks queued for them.

Comment: When all the threads are running the Service is waiting for one of them to get free . Suppose I want to do something here manually then how can I do it. I need to know that it is actually waiting .....